# How many days before the notification of acceptance/rejection does the program committee meet?

Tags: conference, program-committee

In typical conferences in theoretical computer science, how many days before the date of notification of acceptance/rejection,

1. does the program committee meet? (By meeting, I'm not necessarily talking about physical meetings. Discussions via email, easychair can be regarded as meeting here.)
2. does the program committee determine which papers have been accepted / rejected?

In essence my question is: How long before the notification date, it is determined which papers are accepted and which are rejected?

Comment: " program committee meet". In the CS conferences I know of (not theoretical CS) PC members do not necessarily meet in person and discussions are done through email and the respective chair submission system (e.g., easy chair).

Comment: @Alexandros By "meet" here, I assume any kind of meeting, not only physical meetings. I edited the question to make it more clear.